# Enlarge text size for a portion of a document

Tags: tables, formatting, fontsize

For the following code, I would like to make the text in the table larger (say increase the font size by 4pt), but not have it affect any other text in the rest of the document.

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\title{Correction of the test}

%--------------------

\maketitle

\vfill
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc}
         Exercise & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
         \hline
         Points & & & & &
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Place a command such as `\large`, `\Large`,... (depending on the font size you want) inside of the `table` environment, before the start of the `tabular` environment. This will increase the font size of all entries in the table, but will not affect the caption's font size or the font size of the surrounding text.

Comment: Thank you very much. :D

Comment: Evironments, braces, \bgroup/\egroup and \begingroup\endgroup all keep local changes local.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.